# Wordpress Query Random Posts every X amount of hours

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm fairly new to PHP so excuse me if this seems like a dumb question.  I'm building a WP theme for a client, I've gotten the base-functionality down for a "random posts" section, but there's a factor that I'm unable to figure out for myself.

It is a custom post type, that also is utilizing custom fields. The function is, 4 posts from this post type display at random with the required information.

Now: I was able to figure this out on my own, but the random 4 posts is where I'm stumped. The client is requesting that the "Random" aspect only happens every 24 hours instead of every time the page is reloaded.

So basically... how would I alter my existing query so that it only changes the output every 24 hours, instead of every time the page is loaded?

Please see my existing code below:

```
    <ul>
    <?php query_posts("post_type=chapter&orderby=rand&posts_per_page=4");?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <li>
            <div class="authors">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="<?php 
                $post_object = get_field('article_author');

            if( $post_object ): 
            // override $post
            $post = $post_object;
            setup_postdata( $post ); 
            the_field("profile_image");
            $first=get_field("first_name");
            $last=get_field("last_name");
            endif;
            wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>"></a>
                <div class="author-name-home"><?php the_title();?></div>
                <div class="author-title-home"><?php echo $first;?> <?php echo $last;?></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this. Here are some options:

1. Within a nominated post (custom or otherwise), add some additional metadata - you could store the resultant IDs of your 4 random posts (eg: metaname: 'dailyrand' value: '44,55,11,23'). You would have your routine check the time and date of the last time this particular post was updated every time it runs. Once the time and date reaches 24 hours after the last edit, overwrite the metavalue with newly generated random post IDs. If it is not 24 hours yet, pull back the stored post IDs and display. Of course, if the post data changes for some other reason, it could refresh at the wrong interval - maybe it would be better to also set up a time and date metatag to update as well instead of relying on the actual post updated time.
2. Create a table in your database with a few fields (dailyrand, recordtime, postids, etc) and essentially do the same thing. Check each time for 24 hours since the last update to the table and rinse and repeat.
3. Get some plugin or widget to do it for you. :) Here's one: http://wordpress.org/plugins/static-random-posts-widget/ - it doesn't look like it has been updated for a while.

Of course, some may think these are terrible ideas - just offering some quick suggestions as no one has commented as yet.